# Configure service endpoint for angular 4/5 application

Tags: angular, configuration, endpoint

Have angular4 application and web api data service for this application. Have 100 customers of this application and data service. They have this data service and angular application on their IIS. So every of 100 angular application use ANOTHER endpoint address. So angular application in every customer need configuration for setting endpoint address - which have to be set in customer. None constant endpoint can be written into any file of angular application. How to solve this for angular 4/5 application?

Comment: More precisely - endpoint cannot be hardcoded in *.ts (environment*.ts) files - because they cannot be changed in customer. I need client application configuration file, which can be changed individually for every customer. Data service (asp.net web api) is ok, it have his web.config - it works. But config file for angular application seems is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I've seen for this problem is to create a file called **configuration.json** (or whichever name you wish) in the assets folder of your project, and change all of the endpoints when you're deploying on site.

In your code, you should create an angular service that reads the json from the file and exposes it as an object to the parts of your application that require the data service endpoints. This will involve using HttpClient to do a GET request on the configuration.json file.

Additionally, you can use a resolver, which uses the service, to resolve the environment data before navigating to each route.

This article describes the solution well enough: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/deploying-angular-4-apps-with-environment-specific-info/

The main point is that you can change the endpoints in the file and your application will resolve them at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, i found something like this - reading (json) configuration file from assets folders. But - as I see, web application have problem with reading local file - probably because of security. But in some cases - when web api url is similar to web client url, it is possible to read file from assets folder. In some cases I got bad results (invalid path in web application, relative path to assets files did not work good). I found some acceptable solution with usage of APP_INITIALIZER, javascript function - it work wit AOT compiling and in prod mode.